# Removing the "box" of a checkbox in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the actual box of a checkbox field, and just make the text clickable.   How can I do this with JS and css?  I started using buttons, but I switched to checkboxes because the "state" of the box is easier to find out than a button. But now that I am polishing up the page with css for better formatting and layout, The boxes are getting in the way, and I would prefer just for the text to be clickable without a box present.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can just hide it with CSS using `display: none;`

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" value="a" /><label for="a">asdf</label>​
```

CSS

```
/* for all inputs of type checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"]  {
   display: none;
}

/* for just the single element by id */ 
#a {
    display: none; 
    /* visibility: hidden      works too */
}​
```

See here for [difference between `visibility:hidden` and `display:none`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133064/219118).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lerdx/)

Comment: If you use Chrome (FF and IE have it too though I don't use either) you can hit `F12` to pull up the dev tools that has a console. Or just `Ctrl Shift J` to go straight to the console. Makes debugging way easier!

Comment: AH! visibility, not Display!

How would I apply this to all checkboxes?   Would I have to set their classes to the same? or could I use a selector for the checkbox themselves?

Comment: @chrisFrisina Change the `#a` CSS selector to `input[type="checkbox"]` if you want to style all checkboxes in your page without applying classes.

Comment: err actually I had display but changed it. Either will work, the difference is visibility keeps the placeholder of the element where display will collapse it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `appearance: none;`

Note: Not compatible or consistent with all browsers, see [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to treat a piece of text like a button for the purposes of a JS effect, you may want to wrap the text in a span and assign the function you're trying to fire to the onclick handler for that span.  If you were using, say, jQuery, that might look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Your function:
function doSomething() {
    alert('Hello!');
}

// jQuery's on-document-ready function, to assign the
// function doSomething to the click handler of the span.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span#myButtonText").click(function() {
        doSomething();
    });
});
</script>

<p><span id="myButtonText">Click Me for an Alert!</span></p>
```